# Java unable to read chinese characters from Db2 Database

Tags: java, db2, character

I am trying to read from Java application Chinese characters from Db2 database

Db2 database configuration

DB2 database XDSN3T configuration:

[image: DB2 database XDSN3T configuration]

with DB2 CLP data are displayed correctly

[image]

also from another delphi application chinese data are correct

[image]
To obtain this I set:

- Regional and language options, Advanced, non unicode programs --> Chinese RPC

non unicode programs:

[image: non unicode programs]
- enviroment variables, DB2CODEPAGE = 1252

db2codepage:
[image]

Only Java is not able to display data correctly --> ÃæÁÏ¡¢¸¨ÁÏ¡¢¸½¼þ

[image]

Maybe something related to JDBC..

Comment: Please add the code to fetch the data from the DB

Comment: Nota nota  = new Nota();

Comment: nota.Nota = rs.getString("QUANNOTA");

Comment: It's not a Java problem. Seems that the font your tool uses can't render these characters.

Answer (score 0):

When you open the connection you can define the encoding, not sure if it's available for chinese. but here is an example:

`Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://examplehost:8888/dbname?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8","user", "pass");`

Answer (score 0):

As it's been said the encoding might be an issue; characters in java are stored using UTF-16 encoding which has itself some issues regarding the encoding of Chinese (also some emoji) characters.

You can find the character list for UTF-16 here:  https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/UTF-16/list.htm

The issue with UTF-16 comes when characters cannot be encoded using a single 16-bit unit; these characters are encoded using two 16-bit units which is called a surrogate pair. see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#unicode

Sorry I cannot provide a complete answer, but I hope this will help